# How can I use multiple field separators or multiple awk to process columns

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a tab separated file which looks like the following

```
John  1,0   3,2   5,6
Mike  3,2    4,5   0,0
James 3,0    5,3   4,5
```

I would like to add all the first elements of 3 fields and add second elements of 3 fields output the following

```
John 9,8
Mike 9,7
James 12,8
```

Is there is a solution in awk where I can use multiple field separators?

Comment: what's multiple FS is doing there?

Comment: I need to parse the fields by tab and again by "," . Is that right? Sorry, I am a beginner. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: btw why it is `Mike 9,7` instead of `Mike 7,7` in 2nd line?

Comment: and if you have `James 3,0 5,3 4,9` what should it print: `James 12,12` or `James 13,2` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use multiple delimiters in `awk`:

```
awk -F '[\t,]+' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, ($2+$4+$6) "," ($3+$5+$7)}' file

John    9,8
Mike    7,7
James   12,8
```

Comment: what if `($3+$5+$7)` > 9 ? won't propagate to the units. Actually the OP did not specify if numbers should be processed as decimals with coma or as a couple of numbers.

Comment: OP just wants to add both numbers individually. There is no mention that `,` is to be treated like a decimal.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I suspect you're assuming that the `,` is the European decimal fraction separator.  I don't see anything in the question that `3,2` should means the same thing as the `3.2` floating-point syntax.  CLearly, the question is about adding the "first elements of the three fields" and "second elements". So 3,2 is a field and it consists of two sub-field elements: 3 and 2; it is not 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `awk` but here's a (boring) solution with `bash`:

```
while read -r name f1 f2 f3; do
    s1=$((${f1%,*}+${f2%,*}+${f3%,*}))
    s2=$((${f1#*,}+${f2#*,}+${f3#*,}))
    echo "$name $s1,$s2"
done < input.txt
```

Comment: Don't sell it short, it's not just boring it's also extremely slow ;-).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[\t,]' '{delete s; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) s[i%2]+=$i; print $1 "\t" s[0] "," s[1]}' file
John    9,8
Mike    7,7
James   12,8
```